# Installing Haskell Stack builds and artifacts or GHC to a different drive than C:

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, haskell-stack, chocolatey

Is there any good methods to install Haskell on a different drive than C: , such that when I run `stack build`and `stack test` etc., it will not install a large number of files in `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows`
but could essentially be installed in `D:\HaskellStack` or so.

My problem is that I run out of space on my laptop. Especially when building different projects in different folders on a `D:` drive, in  which they still write to the above specified folder and `C:\sr`, so I would really like to know how to avoid that.

**Some specifications**
I use windows 10, and chocolatey 2, mingw, msys2 and haskell-Stack 2.11.1 , but a different approach entirely might be better. I am making only very small Haskell projects max 400 lines of code + some test code. So any suggestions will be appreciated. Even suggestions of how to 'avoid' writing to global environment and rather use project environments on the `D:` when building.

I have looked into [chocolatey install post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752533/how-do-i-set-chocolatey-to-install-applications-onto-another-drive) but these seems to cover packages more overall related to chocolatey, but the haskell package works by itself after installation.
Furthermore I have looked into [reddit posts about it](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/ckt1yt/how_to_change_install_the_binaries_directory_in/) but I don't know if they work (at least I can't see the suggestions cause a change of behavior), and if a global project and the default stack folder specified above will thereby can be avoided.
In the [Stack FAQ](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/faq) it seems that they specify how to change local projects, but my local projects are on `D:` so I think the global project/environment on `C:` will still be linked and build, which will not solve my storage problem.

Comment: Why don't you know if the solutions from reddit work? Have you not tested them? In that case you should go back and properly do your [search and research](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @cafce25 , Thanks  for your quick reply. I could perhaps have been more precise in the chosen formutation. I have indeed tried it, but I don't know if I am following the instructions there correctly. I have tried `stack build--local-bin-path "D:\HaskellStack"` but no such directory seems to be created. Although I don't get an error message. Furthermore the 'global' folder mentioned in my post does seem to take up more space. Hope that clarified things.